# Accessing route values in view Mvc.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using default route of mvc2 like `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. I want to access that `id` field in my view. How can I do that without using `TempData` and `ViewData`?

If I have a url like `http://server-name/home/edit/14` I need the value `"14"` in the view.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can access route data using the ViewContext property:

```
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>
```